# How to best analyze several time series of speed data? Comparing regression analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series

So I have several time series of AIS data, aka time, speed and geographical position at that moment for thousands of ships. They all have that in mutual that they are arriving at the same spot, but have different origin. How could I use these to generalize the speed (in parts of the journey) for the vessels heading to the same sport? Do a regression analysis over all these different time series, then compare the regression analysis for these?

*Edit:*
 I want to give an generalization of how the typical speed through a journey is based on the journey of all the vessels. Is the speed high in the first 50% of the journey, then lower in the last 50%? Is it varying a lot? Ideally I want kind of continuous graph showing the speed on different parts of the journey (maybe down to single &), but I am really unsure if thats the best to describe how the speed along the journey for all these vessels are.

These vessel can travel just a couple hours or across the globe.

The idea is to get a good "oversight" over the general data, before I start any hypothesis testing.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is it you want to know exactly, what the average speed is?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I want to give an generalization of how the typical speed through a journey is based on the journey of all the vessels. Is the speed high in the first 50% of the journey, then lower in the last 50%? Is it varying alot? Etc.

Comment: OK, you want to know how mean speed varies based on what part of the journey a given ship is in. Do the distances differ amongst the ships? Do you have that information?

Comment: Yes, precisely! I hope to - I guess thats a part of the problem I want to solve as well, to give a estimate on how good that estimation is. The distances differ amongst the ships, and I have that info. I hoped I could differantiate the "journey" part in percentage of journey - but should I rather generalize the ships after similar types of journeys?

Comment: You need to clarify a bit more what you mean "through a journey". You could use something like "distance in a straight line from the destination", "distance along the (final) path from the destination", or "percentage of the way along the final path", and they have very different meanings when you think of short hops down the coast versus trips across the Pacific. Do you care about things like currents, areas the ship passes through, etc? Should you? (Depends on the conclusions you want to draw and how strong you want them to be.)

Comment: Probably percentage of the way from origin to destination, where destination is similar for all, while origin varies. The voyages can be trips across the pacific, the atlantic ocean etc - so as long distance as it can be. Right now I just want it to be at the most general level possible to see what conclusions in what confidence I can draw (F.ex all ships have a spike in speed the last 20% of the journey), then later I see my self go into more details (time of year, areas, weather etC).

Comment: Perhaps you could group same departure-arrival journeys in the same group. Then you can compare the journeys inside each group, e.g. mean speed in a give segment.